# JQuery post return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, input

I have a problem with JQuery on a mobile device.

```js
function send() {
  $.post("scripts/post.php", {
    username: $("input[name=username]").val(),
    password: $("input[name=password]").val()
  }, function(data) {
    if ($(".data div").html() == "") {
      $(".data div").html(data);
      $(".data").show();
    } else {
      $('.data div').fadeOut(function() {
        $(".data div").html(data);
        $('.data div').fadeIn();
      });
    }
  });
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return send()">
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="50" required autocomplete="none" value="user">
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="50" required value="password">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign in">
</form>
```

On desktop it works perfectly but on mobile the post is not sending and the page is reloading.

Comment: ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086692/onsubmit-still-submits-when-returning-false

Comment: I suggest changing your button from <input type='submit'> to <input type='button' onclick='send();'>.  I suspect the problem probably lies in using the form submit mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

you need to prevent default form submit using `event.preventDefault()` inside your `send()` method.

Comment: Why wouldn't returning `false` work? Why does mobile make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery works on phones. jQuery mobile is just for more mobile-centric functionality.

I noticed you have a bunch of errors on your website in the developer console. I'd fix those first:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.alweso.2ap.pl/js/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.alweso.2ap.pl/nivo-slider.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.alweso.2ap.pl/lib/jquery.bxslider.css Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier arrow-bounce.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input onemore.js:12 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.alweso.2ap.pl/font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome-4.0.3/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3

It's possible the mobile browser might not be able to recover from these errors, but a desktop one can.

You can find these errors in the JavaScript Console. For Chrome you can open it in a couple ways:

Use the keyboard shortcut Command - Option - J (Mac) or Control -Shift -J (Windows/Linux).
Select View > Developer > JavaScript Console.

Comment: *"I noticed you have a bunch of errors on your website..."* Where did you get the website? It's not in the question.